# c# windows forms - Реализация притяжения планет в космосе 2D

Tags: c#, winforms

Требуется реализовать взаимное притяжение планет (в дальнейшем и других объектов) в космосе. Знаю, что уравнение Кеплера мне в помощь, но долгие вечера с чашкой чая не дали свои плоды

Comment: не уверен что понимаю что вы хотите получить от сообщества

Comment: Совет или возможно частичное решение как реализовать это

Comment: Вам надо расписать подробнее, что вы понимаете под реализацией притяжения. Может ничего реализовывать не надо, а достаточно "нарисовать" планеты на нужных расстояниях друг от друга?

Comment: Вы уже что-то пробовали? Если да. то почему об этом нет ни слова в тексте вопроса. Если нет - самое время попробовать и уточнить в вопросе, что именно не получается. Совет? Ну возьмите подходящий справочник, узнайте нужные уравнения, постройте модель и нарисуйте результат на форме. Нужна динамика - крутите модель в цикле и по таймеру обновляйте изображение. Способов сделать слишком много. С уравнениями не помогу, я хоть и физик по образованию, но в совсем другой области.

Comment: Я понимаю как это реализовать лишь на словах (у каждой планеты есть свое притяжение и она будет притягивать ну к примеру свой спутник, который будет вращаться по эллиптической орбите), а на деле просто прогоняю в голове все сказанное

Comment: Я как то писал подобное, но исходников не осталось. Поглядите это, может, у вас появятся идеи как решить вашу задачу  https://gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=81805